# Prevent Gmail Cleansing of Attached HTML

Tags: html, gmail

I have created a single HTML file that includes its own CSS styling, as well as custom HEAD tags so that it displays in a mobile browser fairly nicely. I then have it working with PHP as a file attachment.

Trouble is this -- Gmail is munging the View of it, but not the Download of it. Gmail is stripping out the CSS and rebuilding the HEAD without my custom viewport stuff.

Is there a programmatic way to code the HTML5 to cause Gmail to fail in doing this cleansing?

Comment: You should include some code (or list of css attributes at least). But basically your question amounts to circumventing a security filter. There's probaby nothing to be done.

Comment: No code necessary. Just compose any HTML at all with CSS physically inside the file (not linked remotely). Doesn't matter what CSS. Mail it to yourself. Click View instead of Download. Google strips said CSS.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. The thing about it is that they strip things in a way that doesn't make sense to me (and it is not a security filter). ID elements in divs are stripped. Inline styles are sometimes stripped (margin-top) and sometimes not (border-collapse, width, etc.).

Comment: Greetings from 2021! Did we find any way to manage this or is the filtering intentional? Can we disable HTML attachments from opening in browser? I actually want to force users to download the html and open it from downloads, but clicking the attachment anywhere but the small download button causes the file to open in gmail's viewer, not as an actual file.

Answer (score 0):

My only advice (and it sucks because it means a lot more work) is to put the styles inline with the html as much as you can. That seems to get past at least some of their filtering.